# strcmp returns unexpected value in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C, I have lines of code look like this:

```
char user[16];
fgets(user,16,stdin);
```

I typed "zeyang" on the keyboard, and I have another code:

```
char pwname[1000];
pwname="zeyang";
```

Then I use `strcmp` to compare user and pwname:

```
strcmp(user, pwname);
```

The return value is a negative number, I expect it to be 0, because they are all "zeyang". Why it isn't 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fgets` includes the typed newline if there's room.  You're comparing `"zeyang\n"` with `"zeyang"`.  From the [`fgets(3)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/):

> The newline, if any, is retained.

Comment: Then what should I do to make it compare "zeyang" with "zeyang"?

Comment: Use `strncmp` or remove the newline from the `user` string.

Comment: Or define pwname to include the newline: `pwname = "zeyang\n";`

Comment: And always listen to Carl Norum. He hates C++, which automatically makes him a Very Good Guy. Seriously.

Comment: `if (user[0]) user[strlen(user)-1] = '\0';` would shorten `user` by one char, removing the newline... (the `if` is just in case the string is empty already).  `strncmp` (in a straightforward way) is not a good choice here because it would allow extra characters and still match.

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao: You can remove the newline character as follows: `char *newline=strchr(user,'\n'); if (newline) *newline=0;`

Comment: The man page does not specify what happens when the `fgets` buffer is *almost* full -- i.e., room for a `0` but not for the Return. Would that be an error, or can you rely on the last character *always* being "the" return? (Edit: I always do exactly what @JohnBode suggest above.)

Comment: @Jongware it likely doesn't matter as long as the buffer is a couple of chars longer than any valid user...

Comment: @Jongware: from the online C2011 standard: "The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters speciﬁed by n
from the stream pointed to by `stream` into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-ﬁle. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array."  The newline character will only be stored if there's room for it *and* the 0 terminator.

Answer (score 2):

The first string coming from stdin contains an additional newline character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sentence you enter will be terminated by a new line character. (I guess you pressed ENTER when you have finished to insert characters. :D

In this case I would use [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/) :

```
strncmp(user,pwname,strlen(pwname));
```

This code won't compare the new line character.

Comment: ...but this would also match if he typed a longer, incorrect string if the first part matches... such as "zeyangAndABitMore"

Comment: that's true. It was just an example. He could just  remove the "newLine" character from the input string.